# Сделать верстку на вордпресс при этом не используя все функции вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Есть лендинг который нужно сделать в вордпресс, в самом лендинге нет частей которые будут часто обновляться или изменяться. Я нашел в одном из ответов на SO такое:

> Создание шаблона WP состоит из нескольких этапов:
>
> 1. Создание дизайна
> 2. Верстка
> 3. Добавление динамических элементов WP

У меня есть дизайн, и мне нужно это сверстать, я хочу сделать просто используя HTML\CSS JS, особо не углубляясь в использование функций WP (без добавления динамических элементов), т.е. сделать таким образом тему и использовать ее, без какой либо динамики со стороны вордпресс. Кроме как используя самые стандартные `get_header()` `get_footer()` и т.п. Будет ли это как то влиять на работу сайта, интересно, особо, влияние относительно продвижения сайта. 
В чем минусы и плюсы? Или это вовсе глупо и стоит делать чисто на HTML\CSS JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сверстать тему и не использовать при этом ни одной функции WP, на работу влиять это не будет, а поисковикам вообще все равно как вы там делаете сайт.

Но если вам не нужны функции WP, зачем вам WP? Делайте статический сайт.

Плюс: сайт работает быстро.

Минус: так вы сможете сделать и управлять только самым примитивным сайтом.

Comment: что значит управлять примитивным сайтом?

Comment: На 5 страниц...

Comment: аа, так у меня не целый сайт. одностраничник только

Comment: Тем более, для одностраничника CMS не нужна

Comment: Вот есть же ещё плагины для продвижения какие-то?

Comment: Да, нужны, когда у вас сайт на 1000 страниц. В вашем случае, все можно прописать и так.

Comment: ясно. этот ответ вполне удовлетворяет