# Делать сайт без верстки на WP?

Tags: wordpress

Дали задания из Ворда сверстать сайт на WP.

В Ворде я вижу просто блоки: сайт и контент в нём.

У меня вопрос: это делается, наверное, с помощью какого-то плагина, ибо я привык верстать сайты с нуля, и это задание поставило меня в ступор.

Comment: недавно задавал такого рода вопрос, вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112140/Сделать-верстку-на-вордпресс-при-этом-не-используя-все-функции-вордпресс

Comment: От задания откажись и начни с изучения что такое CMS в принципе.

Comment: вы очень умны, но я сюда пришёл за ответом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На wordpress есть разные плагины, позволяющие сделать из данной CMS полноценный конструктор, например Elementor (Pro), Page Builder, Beaver Builder. Правда у них есть существенный минус присущий практически всем конструкторам - это низкая скорость загрузки сайта. Свой код легче, чем тот, что предлагают конструкторы. Поэтому лучше освоить азы WP и сделать свою тему с натяжкой верстки. Есть огромное множество бесплатных курсов и форумов заточенных конкретно под эту cms. Я вначале своего пути пользовался [clubwp](https://clubwp.ru/). Попробуйте разобраться с самыми простыми вещами: иерархия файлов шаблона, настройка собственной темы, хуками и тд. Неплохо будет подучить основы PHP, т.к при натяжки кода он вам тоже понадобится.